# jQuery detect whether an element has been linked to

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I want to attach a jQuery event handler to a `<div>` element such that whenever a link is clicked which points to this `<div>`, that handler is activated and the associated function is executed – regardless of the location of the link (same page, other page, other site) pointing to the `<div>` .

```
$("div#mydiv").on("linked_to", function(){ //is there a "linked_to" event?
  //do something about it
});
```

Is this possible? Can `scrollIntoView()` be used?

Comment: No. You can write `.on('whateverYouLike' fn)` but unless an event of that type occurs, or is artificially triggered, the handler won't fire. The mere existence of something somewhere else in the universe is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is quite specific and borderline undoable. I think your best bet is to **detect a hash change in the URL** and act accordingly.

You aren't gonna be able to detect that `div#mydiv` itself was clicked, but detecting the hash `#mydiv` comes pretty close to it.

You would use something like:

```
  window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.location.hash === '#mydiv') { // here you check if it was `#mydiv`
      alert('hey! are you after mydiv?!')
    }
  }
```

Check an example here: http://output.jsbin.com/pikifov - click the link and notice how the hash from the URL changes.

Source for the [JSBin above here](http://jsbin.com/pikifov/edit?html,output).

Full code:

```html
<div id="mydiv">mydiv</div>

<hr>

<a href="#mydiv">Click to go to mydiv</a>

<script>
  window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.location.hash === '#mydiv') {
      alert('hey! are you after mydiv?!')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes that seems close enough. Thanks! I kind of guessed I was asking the impossible, but javascript (especially when using jQuery) seems so powerful it sometimes blurs the boundary in my mind :)